# Loop array according how deep it is

Tags: javascript, arrays, typescript

Ok first sorry if the title does not explain well the issue I didn't know how to call it, so I have an array of objects that looks like this:

```
  "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
  "Style": "Number",
  "Id": "c59d36e2-2a60-4223-82f3-d48a22140655",
  "Content": ["4f2a412c-2f46-4463-8855-1ae320074811", {
    "$type": "ElementDTO",
    "Id": "9784a5eb-cafb-4193-8aeb-f431cae8e69e",
    "Content": ["e5c7bb45-3bb0-40bd-a3a2-1fbf847124fd", {
      "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
      "Style": "Number",
      "Id": "84fa3127-54da-4ccf-99e0-fa25ca50faca",
      "Content": ["9f68bc57-d42c-4cd7-94bd-a3905a5d9b82", {
        "$type": "ElementDTO",
        "Id": "ab55aaaf-decc-4cd4-9652-8c7ef4f51ec7",
        "Content": ["3a5242e5-1a26-4444-b072-bc34a62db161", {
          "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
          "Style": "Disc",
          "Id": "7957bca7-34ea-4962-a662-be68e1097ac2",
          "Content": ["ffacd2c4-8029-442c-b6c6-8bf99606ec10", "5558f28a-9dc8-401a-a1fe-381202163250"]
        }]
      }, "8077515c-bc10-4102-9bf9-17593d4831e9"]
    }]
  }, {
    "$type": "ElementDTO",
    "Id": "400b94c9-ae0f-46da-967a-1bf5854983c6",
    "Content": ["2d26fa94-2457-4d7c-baf1-5660a0a81046", {
      "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
      "Style": "Disc",
      "Id": "b690c3d5-47aa-4788-ba67-d20546f98a10",
      "Content": ["86f1fb17-8516-403f-b5ff-0150f444e373", {
        "$type": "ElementDTO",
        "Id": "88b193a7-4978-4e91-9b14-ff483c0c2bc1",
        "Content": ["984f37c4-045b-4ce7-bca7-32ba72cb4f08", {
          "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
          "Style": "Number",
          "Id": "57e3a868-4e67-4b58-88b0-3dff9ea7ed1d",
          "Content": ["f485dc2a-8871-4d23-a688-823ea7f4bb87", {
            "$type": "ElementDTO",
            "Id": "2729ee34-de7a-4a90-9a11-7824a776e4b6",
            "Content": ["5112151d-6f56-4fec-8f39-8c6d757a3145", {
              "$type": "EnumerationElementDTO",
              "Style": "Number",
              "Id": "c9a7ef3f-ae36-4afb-ab47-fbf430f342e3",
              "Content": ["04d00a01-b142-47d1-bc09-b5076b8a3824", "343d7b69-a9ae-4121-bf94-75c1e70a835c"]
            }]
          }]
        }]
      }, "501609f9-9a64-4c93-aac5-d86e387c882b"]
    }]
  }]
```

Now I need to loop the property `"content"` of the objects which is an array, as you can see some times elements on the array are strings or objects, so I loop array `"content"` and I create a conditional that check the type of the element, if the element is type string I do something with it if is and object I go inside of the object and loop the property `"content"` of that object, and make the same process again, now the max deepness is gonna be 9 levels deep,for the most easy way is creating a loop for each one of the array levels example:

```
object.content.forEach((e) => {
  if(typeof e === 'string') {
    // Do something here with the string
  }else {
    e.content.forEach((c => {
      if(typeof c === 'string') {
        // Do something here with the string
      } else {
        c.content.forEach((d) => {
          if(typeof d === 'string') {
            // Do something here with the string
          } else {
            d.content.forEach((f) => {
              if(typeof f === 'string') {
                // Do something here with the string
              } else {

              }
            });

          }
        });

      }
    });
  }
});
```

And that way until reach the 9 levels of deepness of the object, the question is, is there any way to do this in more optimal way?

Comment: I suggest you research the concept of "recursion"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could go and do the amount of if/else checks you need.

But the code will be hard to understand and hard to maintain.

You can use recursion, and for the idea look at the revised code snippet:

```
function handleElement(e) {
    if(typeof e === 'string') {
        // Do something here with the string
    }else {
        e.content.forEach(handleElement);
    }
}
object.content.forEach(handleElement);
```

recursion on Wikipedia:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion_(computer_science)